# Return JSON with unobtrusive

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have the following code where I use Ajax.Beginform:

```
 <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("LogIn", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "target",
                OnSuccess = "ajaxSuccess"
            }, null))
            {
                <div class="sign_up_container">
                    Email:<br />
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Login.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "sign_up_container_input_style" } })<br/>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Login.Email, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="sign_up_container">
                    Password:<br />
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Login.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "sign_up_container_input_style" } })
                    <br/><a href="#">Forgott password?</a>
                </div>
                <div class="sign_up_container">
                    <br />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn_style_3 btn">Login</button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

The validation works. When I enter a invalid email and hits Login, unobtrusive kicks In and says that I must enter a valid Email.

However, now I want to show a message that says that the Username or password is invalid If the user enters a invalid username or password. I have tried to do like this in my LogIn-method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Login(homeIndexViewModel model)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json(new { ModelState = "Something went wrong during login" });
        }

        var user = await userManager.FindAsync(model.Login.Email, model.Login.Password);

        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignIn(user);
            //return Json(new { RedirectAction = GetRedirectUrl(model.Login.ReturnUrl, user.UserId) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);               
        }

        return Json(new { ModelState = "Invalid email or password" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In my Index.cshtml I'm trying to catch the json like this:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        function ajaxSuccess(result) {
            console.log(result); //Contains error message, show It
        }
    });
```

The problem I have is that when I hit Login, I'm redirected to a white page with a json-string printed out with the message:

[image]

Comment: Because you have not included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in your view so `Ajax.BeginForm` is just making a normal submit and redirecting

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Doh.. Thank you.

Comment: But what is the point of this - he whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page - why in the world would you want to stay on the same page if the login is successful - the user does not want to keep logging in!. Make a normal submit (and if `ModelState` is invalid, return the view, otherwise redirect)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I have added that when the login is successful, the user is redirected to another page.

Comment: What your doing is sending back a url back to the client and then redirecting instead of redirecting directly in the post method (that is just crazy).

Comment: @StephenMuecke:As you can see, I have comment that out. Im not doing that anymore. So no crazy stuff there anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139685/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-bryan).